# using my ADODB.Connection to open webconfigs appSettings key?

Tags: vb.net, asp-classic, web-config, connection, adodb

*So I'm stuck on this. Using using VB, Classic ASP. I want to use the code labled 1.) Broken Code because I want the dbs_connection to come from my site main web.config, currently the site hard codes the .asp file to grab the connection, see 2.) This Code Works, so when we have a DB move for instance this gets over looked and broken.*

#### 1.) Broken code.

```
'.Asp file
dim dbs_connection = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("ConnectString_dbs")
dim objRecordSet,DatabaseQueryString
set objConnection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConnection.open dbs_connection

'root web.config note:this works have many other keys in here<br/> 
<appSettings>
<add key="dbs_connection" value="Provider=sqloledb;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Data Source=VDB022;Initial Catalog=dbs;User ID=average; Password=@v3r@@3;OLE DB Services = -1;"/><br/>
<appSettings>
```

#### Error

```
Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a0401' 

Expected end of statement 

/Sites/includes/DisplayDocAdminRepLinks.asp, line 35 

dim dbs_connection = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("ConnectString_dbs")
```

#### 2.) This code works

```
const dbs_connection = "Provider=sqloledb;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Data Source=DB022;Initial Catalog=dbs;User ID=average; Password=@v3r@@3;OLE DB Services = -1;"

dim objRecordSet,DatabaseQueryString
set objConnection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConnection.open dbs_connection
```

Comment: Sounds like you're mixing Classic ASP and ASP.Net together...

Comment: No. See the This code works? I Just need dbs_connection to pull from a web.config file or apparently a golbal.asa file rather than declaring my connection string (the provider, Data Source, ect) in the same document for obvious maintenance reasons. If I'm going about it the wrong way an example is need.

Comment: `ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings` is .Net class for pulling configuration information from the web.config file. VBScript (which is the engine used by Classic ASP) doesn't know of that class which will cause an error. The error your getting at the moment is because your trying to assign a dynamic value to a constant, a constant has to be a static value it doesn't accept dynamic content. To see your next error change the line `const dbs_connection` to `Dim dbs_connection` and underneath `dbs_connection = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("ConnectString_dbs")`, then you will get another error.

Comment: Understood made ur suggested edit to question above also, `Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a0401' 

Expected end of statement 

/Sites/includes/DisplayDocAdminRepLinks.asp, line 35 

dim dbs_connection = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("ConnectString_dbs")`

Comment: In VBScript you can't declare a variable and assign it on the same line use `dim dbs_connection` then on the next line `dbs_connection = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("ConnectString_dbs")` it will still error because Classic ASP will not know what to do with `ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings`.

Comment: @Lankymart of course you can declare a variable and assign a value in one line in vbscript:                      dim myVar : myVar = "ASP.NET IS NOT classic ASP!!!!"

Comment: @ulluoink That is just a shortcut way of displaying two lines on one line not the same as declaring and assigning on the one line, as you can do that with any VBScript code not just a declaration.

Answer (score -1):

you do not have Access to web.config through classic asp. web.config ist ASP.net

usually one uses the global.asa to store such things asa connectsionstrings in classic asp

*example global.asa:*

```
<script language="VBScript" runat="Server">
sub session_OnStart
    session("dbs_connection") = "Provider=sqloledb;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Data Source=DB022;Initial Catalog=dbs;User ID=average; Password=@v3r@@3;OLE DB Services = -1;"

end Sub
</script>
```

*example asp file:*

```
dim objRecordSet, DatabaseQueryString
set objConnection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConnection.open session("dbs_connection")
```

Comment: Whoa nice, looked in global.asa file and had a connection in there pointing to an old Database, actually fixed a 500 error I was getting on another page. As for using Global.asa to replace my 2.) This code works section could you provide an example and I will try it.

Comment: well that depends how you want to implement the SQL Connections thing... have a look here for global.asa description: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525316(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Ok so i put in that first block into my global.asa file, i looked it over and that file is only being used to log people into the website, and load certain permissions. Do i need a transfer or include for the .asa file in my .asp file? `Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005' 

[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified 

/Sites/includes/DisplayDocAdminRepLinks.asp, line 45`

Comment: @NRz the global.asa is automatically processed you do not Need a include. do a Response.write of your session variable to see if it is properly set.